# How to install Geth on Linux Mint LMDE 5 Elsie?

Tags: go-ethereum, linux, debian

I am new to the Linux ecosystem. I just installed Linux Mint LMDE 5 Elsie as my OS, and I want to run a full ethereum node on it. Following the official installation link (https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/getting-started/installing-geth), I entered `sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ethereum/ethereum`, but it says `Adding PPAs is not supported`.

I have also tried creating the `ethereum.list` file inside `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` as suggested [here](https://www.tecmint.com/add-apt-repository/), but it doesn't work. Additionally, I tried `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates` as suggested [here](https://itsfoss.com/fix-add-ppa-error-ubuntu-1404-linux-mint/), it also doesn't work.

Comment: The LMDE is debian based and it doesn't support ubuntu ppas. https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=390460.